# read access violation when I tried to implement Depth First Search algorithm in c++

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

this is my DFS function. I don't know why visited[start_vertex] doesn't work although I allocated the visited array in the main function!

```
                    typedef Node** PtP;
                    void DFS(PtP list, int start_vertex, bool* visited)
                    {
                        cout << "the crash under this line";
                        if (visited[start_vertex])
                        {
                            cout << "ignore";
                        }
                        visited[start_vertex] = true;
                        Node* adj = list[start_vertex];  // linked list list[0]
                        //  after this line start_vertex will be adjacency vertex of start vertex
                        while (adj != NULL)
                        {
    
    
                            DFS(list, adj->data, visited);
                            adj = adj->next;
    
                        }
                    }
```

this is my main function I created an bool array and allocated its by four element and plug in the DFS function

```
int main()
{
    PtP list;
    list = new Node * [4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        list[i] = new Node[4];
        list[i] = NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter number of vertices adjacency with " << i << ": ";
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        addEdge2(list, i, temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "list[" << i << "]: ";
        traverse(list[i]);
    }
    bool* visited = new bool[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        visited = false;
    }
    DFS(list, 0, visited);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "visisted: " << visited[i] << " ";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        delete [] list[i];
    }
    delete [] list;
    return 0;

}
```

and this is my entire program just for test DFS method:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Node {
public: 
    int data;
    Node* next;
    
};
typedef Node* Ptr;
typedef Node** PtP;

void addFront(Ptr& First, int x)
{
    Ptr p;
    p = new Node;
    p->data = x;
    p->next = First;
    First = p;
}
void addEdge(PtP &list, int v1, int v2)
{
    addFront(list[v1], v2);
    addFront(list[v2], v1);

}

void addEdge2(PtP& list, int v, int num_of_adj_vtex)
{
    cout << "enter vertices adjacency with  " << v << ": ";
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_adj_vtex; i++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        addFront(list[v], temp);
    }
}
void traverse(Node* first)
{
    Node* p = first;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->data<<" ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}


void DFS(PtP list, int start_vertex, bool* visited)
{
    
    if (visited[start_vertex])
    {
        
        cout << "vertex: " << start_vertex << " visited ";
    }
    visited[start_vertex] = true;
     // linked list list[0] after this line start_vertex will be adjaceny vertex of start vertex
    Node* adj = list[start_vertex];
    while (adj != NULL)
    {


        DFS(list, adj->data, visited);
        adj = adj->next;

    }
}
int main()
{
    PtP list; //type def node ** ptp
    list = new Node * [4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        list[i] = NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter number of vertices adjacency with " << i << ": ";
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        addEdge2(list, i, temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "list[" << i << "]: ";
        traverse(list[i]);
    }
    bool* visited = new bool[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        visited[i] = false;
    }
    DFS(list, 0, visited);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "visisted: " << i << " "<< visited[i] << " ";
    }




    delete [] list;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: post code not an image

Comment: "All of your code" is most likely too much, but nonetheless you should try to produce a [mcve]. In this case it's safe to assume the value for `visited`, `start_vertex` or both are incorrect, but there's not enough info to determine why they are incorrect. Please [edit] the question and add the parts of your code that are necessary to determine the issue. At least we should be able to see where `visited` and `start_vertex` come from; be sure to include the allocation of the `visited` array and anything that could result in its deallocation between allocation and function call.

Comment: Note If you ask a "Help me fix this code" question without a [mre], odds are really good that by the time you can comply and supply the MRE the question will have been locked and you could find yourself waiting hours for it to be unlocked. Make the MRE early in the question writing process because not only is the question more likely to come to a satisfactory ending, but MRE is a great debugging technique. Usually you get part way in to making one and the reduced noise in the code makes the bug and solution obvious. At that point you probably don't have a question anymore.

Comment: I fixed my question, tks you guys. I'm still don't know why my visited[start_vertex] crash! pls help me

Comment: It looks like the DFS method runs the risk of going out of the bounds of the array depending on what adj->data is.  It looks like that data is pointing to something > 3 for the error to be happening. If you could post some more code we could be sure, but that's the most likely issue

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond tks, I'll check again and post some more of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from what I can see, the problem seems to be user input related. The method:

```cpp
void addEdge2(PtP& list, int v, int num_of_adj_vtex)
{
    cout << "enter vertices adjacency with  " << v << ": ";
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_adj_vtex; i++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        addFront(list[v], temp); //Here if temp > 3 your later code will fail.
    }
}
```

Requests user input and stores it at the front of the list...whatever is the value of temp, and puts it into the data field.

Later on when you do the `DFS` method you call the same method recursively:

```cpp
        DFS(list, adj->data, visited);
        adj = adj->next;
```

This depends on what adj->data has stored, from the addEdge2 function. Since you have set the boolean array to a length of 4, that adj->data must be pointing to any value > 3 which would throw the error you mentioned because it is trying to access unallocated memory.

It seems like the code is not wrong, exactly, even though you could probably set some safeguards like making sure the user enters a value from 0 to 3.